# Small read cache on SSD (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a question concerning performance settings/setup in MySQL DB/InnoDB.
The server has SSD disks so general access to data is fast. Although there is enough of RAM, but enough is never enough and I must make some limitations somewhere.

Does it make sense to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_size and read_buffer_size - and use available RAM to increase sort_buffer_size, join_buffer_size, tmp_table_size, max-heap-table-size - so that joins and temporary tables would not be written to disk at all?

In other words - I want to reduce disk read cache (because SSD can read data really fast) and increase RAM for joins and for temporary tables, to avoid tables written to disk (i.e. make all temporary activity in RAM only). Yes, I know that SSD write is also faster than HDD write, but if I can avoid/minimize disk write - then query execution would be even faster.

Thank you for your opinions.

Comment: A more careful examination of mysql status is needed, globally for innodb_buffer_pool usage and per session based for other buffers. Temporary  tables written to disk may not be flushed so might remain in page cache. If the query execution speed is the goal then enable the slow query log and start to look at them. Frequently better written queries or added indexes result in better queries more than system variable tuning.

Comment: Generally, making those tuning changes won't help much, and may hurt.  More steps to provide data to help you:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: This is more theoretical question on configuration approach, not a specific issue of a slow working server. General concept "add more RAM" seems to be universal, I was thinking of optimization of existing RAM by using fast SSDs for read and thus reducing read-cache.